# os.path.join issue Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.path

I am having some issues with `os.path.join` and a Windows system.  I have created a script that recursively reads files containing unstructured JSON data, creates a directory named "converted_json", and prints the content of each unstructured JSON file in a structured format into a new file within the "converted_json" directory.

I have tested the script below on macOS and upon execution, the structured JSON data is printed to new files and the new files are output to the "converted_json" directory.  However, when I execute the script on a Windows system, the JSON data is printed to new files, but the files are not output to the "converted_json" directory.

Essentially, the following `os.path.joi`n code does not appear to be working on Windows in the following section:

```
conv_json = open(os.path.join(converted_dir, str(file_name[-1]) + '_converted'), 'wb')
```

The files are created, however they are not stored within the "converted_json" directory that is specified by the converted_dir variable.

The following output is from printing the "conv_json" variable:

*open file 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\test\file_name.json.gz.json_converted', mode 'wb' at 0x0000000002617930*

As seen from above, the file path contained within the "conv_json" variable does not contain the "converted_json" directory (it should be there from using os.path.join and the converted_dir variable.

Any assistance as to how to get the structured data to output to the "converted_json" directory would be greatly appreciated.

Code below:

```
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument('-d', '--d', dest='dir_path', type=str, default=None, required=True, help='Directory path to Archive/JSON files')
args = argparser.parse_args()
dir_path = args.dir_path


converted_dir = os.path.join(dir_path, 'converted_json')
os.mkdir(converted_dir, 0777)

for subdir1, dirs1, files1 in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file in files1:

        try:
            if file.endswith(".json"):
                file = open(os.path.join(subdir1, file))
                file_name = str.split(file.name, '/')

                conv_json = open(os.path.join(converted_dir, str(file_name[-1]) + '_converted'), 'wb')

                conv_json.write('#################################################################################################################################')
                conv_json.write('\n')
                conv_json.write('File Name: ' + file_name[-1])
                conv_json.write('\n')
                conv_json.write('#################################################################################################################################')
                conv_json.write('\n')

                parsed_json = json.load(file)
                s = cStringIO.StringIO()
                pprint.pprint(parsed_json, s)

                conv_json.write(s.getvalue())

                conv_json.close()

        except:
            print 'JSON Files Not Found'

print 'JSON Processing Completed: ' + str(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this line is bad on Windows:

```
file_name = str.split(file.name, '/')
```

The split on '/' will not split at all.  You should use os.path.sep instead.

I think os.path.join reacts so confusing since the second part you try to join is already a full file path (since the split failed).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I will look into your suggestion.  Thanks!